# Is it possible to increase the playback speed of a Camtasia project, but not the actual speed of the video?

Tags: video, camtasia

I'm editing a Camtasia project, and I find myself watching it at a slow pace, where I realise that watching it at twice the speed would allow me to finish editing in half the time. However, since I am adding annotations, cutting things up and whatnot, editing the actual speed of each clip is not a very practical solution for me.

Is there a way to increase the playback speed for a video within Camtasia only, and still maintain the same original speed when exported?

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know of is this.

1. > Make sure you are focused on the timeline (click it) and then hit CTRL + A. This will select all editable media on the timeline.
2. > Navigate to visual effects, select clip speed, and drag it on to any piece of media. It will be applied to all pieces of media.
3. > While all clips are selected (VIA CTRL + A) you can easily set the playback speed of all clips in the properties window, under clip speed. This change will be applied to all media.
4. > Before rendering your media, you can set the playback to normal or remove the clip speed from all tracks.

Unfortunately not the best solution but it is the only thing I've found that works.

Comment: Robbie, you are my hero! Thank you so much :) I never thought of doing it this way and you just saved me HOURS!!!

Answer (score 1):

As of the 27th June of 2023, Camtasia (2023.1.0) now has playback speed control out of the box.

**How to use Playback Speed Controls in Camtasia**

While in the video in Editor, use the following keys:

`J` To slow down or play backwards
`K` To stop/pause the playback
`L` To play. Press again to increase the playback speed while editing (up to 8x)

See full instructions in [this official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2MwymZ-5sQ).